# What callbacks i must to register,to catch start and end of paragraf and any other structures in lualatex

Tags: luatex

Help me please,what callbacks i must register to catch starting and ending of structures in lualatex such as paragrafs,lists,items of lists,tables,sections,subsections,sub...subsections,ETC. How i can learn,what the structure start or end in this moment and get and change content of this structure,if it need. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Most callbacks operate on full paragraphs.  You have to be more specific about what you want to do to the paragraph.

Comment: If you are inspecting the shipout box, paragraphs are contained in `local_par` sublists.

Comment: If you mean LaTeX structures like `\begin{section}` or `\begin{itemize}`, then unfortunately LuaTeX has no native understanding of these structures, as all of LaTeX is implemented in TeX macros and as far as TeX/LuaTeX is considered, all of these are just `\def`s that expand to some stream of tokens or another.